# Using perl to run more than one system command in a row

Tags: perl

I'm trying to script some things on my team's server and having some difficulty.

For part of what I'm scripting, I need to have the user switch user via `sudo su APPUSER` and then run several commands. However, sudo is rather locked down on our server and I cannot run something like: `sudo su APPUSER -c COMMAND`. I've asked for that to be fixed, by the system admins always say, "no".

I am currently using perl to do the scripting, and I need to drop into the appuser instead of the developer's user to run about three commands. I can do it on the command line by executing each command in succession, but I do not know how to get perl to do that.

How can I make perl execute more than one command on the command line in a way that it does not discard the shell/state after the previous execution? i.e., running multiple `system` calls doesn't work.

Comment: Why not put the commands in a shell script and use perl to run that?

Comment: why perl when already in shell and using only `system`

Comment: Because the scripts whether shell or perl, are executing initially as the dev user. Neither can successfully drop into the appuser unless done manually, which is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Open a bash process and read and write to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(BASH, "|-", "bash");

print BASH "sudo su APPUSER\n";
print BASH "touch /home/APPUSER/sudobashtest\n";
close(BASH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
system("sudo su APPUSER && command1 && command2");
```

Comment: No, that will run sudo su as the app user, and then run command1 and command2 after you exit the APPUSER's shell.